# Biblatex's \printbibliography not working

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I am a beginner with LaTeX, so it might be something really obvious that I am missing. I am using TeXstudio as an editor if it makes any difference.

I have the following code in my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12p,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\title{My title}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

....

\newpage    
\printbibheading
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

Inside my `citations.bib` file I have:

```
@book{rasmussen,
    author    = "C. E. Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams",
    title     = "Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning",
    year      = "2006",
    publisher = "MIT Press",
    address   = "Massachusetts Institute of Technology"
}
```

Inside my `.tex` document I am citing it as `\cite{rasmussen}`, but there is no citation at the end of my file.

So, to sum up, my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12p,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\title{My Title}

% For the citations
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}

\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \cite{rasmussen}

\newpage
\printbibheading
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get the following error message when running `bibtex myFile`:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: dissertation.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
I couldn't open database file citations.bib
---line 3 of file dissertation.aux
 : \bibdata{dissertation-blx,citations
 :                                    }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: dissertation-blx.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "F1:2010:Online"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "rasmussen"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "GP:Columbia"
Biblatex version: 2.8
(There was 1 error message)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). If you issue both `\printbibheading` and `\printbibliography` you will have 2 bibliography headings. Also, there is an error in your `.bib` file: `&` should be `and`.

Comment: Thank you! If I delete the `\printbibheading` command I have no heading at all, so there might be something wrong with `\printbibliography` ? Corrected the `.bib`, no changes.

Comment: Please post some compilable code (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @karlkoeller, I edited the initial post.

Comment: Did you run bibtex?

Comment: @cgnieder: I edited my initial post with what happens when running bibtex.

Comment: so where do you put your .bib file? If it is in another directory, you should link the path. Example: `\addbibresource{./tex/njoy.bib}`.

Comment: @selwyndd21: No, my `.bib` file is in the same folder as the main `.tex` file.

Comment: @cgf I get the expected result; the error message is quite clear: the `citations.bib` file can't be found, so either it has a different name or it is misplaced. Note that you should use `and`, not `&` to separate author names in the `.bib` file.